# Broadcasting Internet from a WiFi router to another, and then to a PC via Ethernet cable

Tags: windows, router, wireless-networking, ethernet, tethering

I'm trying to connect a Windows XP PC (that has no integrated Wi-Fi capability) to my wireless Internet network. I have a spare wireless router (ZyXEL P-660HW-T1 v2) so I was hoping It could connect to the wireless network, and then connect the PC to it through an Ethernet cable. Is this possible? If it is, what's the correct router setup?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I've done this one for a friend. Many wireless routers can't do this out of the box. Its called "Bridged Mode". However, if it has this functionality, or you have a router compatible with Tomato or DD-WRT, you can re-flash the firmware on the router to get this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think this would work, as the PC would be only be connecting to the spare wireless router, which creates a different wireless network than the wireless Internet network that you are using right now.

The best thing to do would be to install a WiFi card into your motherboard of the Windows PC, or use a Wireless USB dongle.